# Bootstrap col align right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a row with 2 cols. One col on the left with its contents aligned left, and the second col with its contents aligned right (old pull-right).

How to do I go about this in alpha-6?

I've tried a few things, but this is what I have so far. What am I missing?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">left</div>
    <div class="col ml-auto">content needs to be right aligned</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the new version of bootstrap, I found this working shortcut :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction

Answer (score 319, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

To right align elements in Bootstrap 5...

`float-right` is now `float-end`
`text-right` is now `text-end`
`ml-auto` is now `ms-auto`

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Use **`float-right`** for block elements, or **`text-right`** for inline elements:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col">left</div>
     <div class="col text-right">inline content needs to be right aligned</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">left</div>
      <div class="col">
          <div class="float-right">element needs to be right aligned</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/oPTBdCw1JV

**If `float-right` is not working,** remember that **Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox**, and many elements are `display:flex` which can prevent `float-right` from working.

In some cases, the utility classes like **`align-self-end`** or **`ml-auto`** work to right align elements that are inside a flexbox container like the Bootstrap 4 .row, Card or Nav. The `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) is used in a flexbox element to push elements to the right.

[Bootstrap 4 align right examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/nTobetXAwb)

Answer (score 59):

How about this? **Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-3">
        The content is positioned as if there was
        "col-9" classed div appending this one.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Life saviour.. Thank you :)

Comment: justify-content-end is just life saving.

Answer (score 40):

For Bootstrap 4 I find the following very handy because:

- the column on the right takes exactly the space it needs and will pull right
- while the left col always gets the maximum amount of space!.

It is the combination of **col** and **col-auto** which does the magic. So you don't have to define a col width (like col-2,...)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Left</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Right</div>
</div>
```

Ideal for aligning words, icons, buttons,... to the right.

An example to have this responsive on small devices:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Left</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto">Right (Left on small)</div>
</div>
```

Check this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/tx08zveL/

Comment: col-auto looks weird, but it's the first thing that worked after many unsuccessful attempts to do horizontal alignment for non-float buttons during half a day :)

Comment: I find this the better solution for my scenario.

Comment: It works great with **Bootstrap 5** too.

Answer (score 4):

For The Bootstrap 4+

This Code Worked Well for me

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="ml-auto">
                this content will be in the Right
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mr-auto">
            <div class="mr-auto">
                this content will be in the leftt
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation, you do it like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">left</div>
    <div class="col-md-push-6">content needs to be right aligned</div>
</div>
```

[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Comment: @Guilherme , the bootstrap 4 tags were added by someone else (after I had answered). The original question only had twitter-bootstrap tag.